# WCF Services: Dropped connection handling

Tags: c#, transactions, wcf, wcf-client

Have a WCF Service being called to update records in the database.  If the connection is broken, the service will continue to process the data, but the client won't know of the results.  I.E. the processing could have succeeded or failed; the client doesn't know if it should resend the data.

Typical example would be a bank deposit.  An ATM takes a deposit and makes a WCF call to update the customer's account.  The connection is dropped, leaving the ATM uncertain as to whether the deposit was processed or not.  If it wasn't, and the ATM doesn't resend, the customer doesn't have the money in his account.  If the ATM resends, but the deposit was processed, he'll have two deposits.

Enabling transactions on the WCF Service call seems the thing to do, but can they handle a dropped connection?  I.E. the client can roll back the transaction if it loses connection to the server, but how would the server know about the rollback if the client isn't connected?

Comment: er... is "TIA, James" not appropriate to add to a question?  Why did you delete that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that any way you look at it, there is a possible issue for serious catastrophic failure.

Assuming that you are using async client calls and/or the ammount of processing being done on the service side is relatively large.  If in the span of the ammount of time, the connection to the service from the client is severed, there is no way for the client to know what state the service was last left in. If it was mid-transaction, the service side transaction will be cancled automatically... if it was post-transaction then your work is done... but in both situations the client will "never know".

Theoretically... (and don't quote me on this, but it SOUNDS like a logical scenario) if an ATM loses connection in the process of doing a deposit... I believe (and like I said don't quote me on this) that the ATM itself keeps a list of transaction in memory so that in a situation where a transaction fails, once the connection is re-established it can check itself and verify if the transaction was actually completed.  (If it in reality doesn't do this... I would be a bit concerned personally).

To make a long story short... I believe the only thing you can do in this scenario is to have the client side keep some sort of checksum which would match with the service side so that if a connection failure occurred, when the connection was re-established, it would be able to check against the service to see if the transaction did in fact complete or not.

Comment: Checking once the connection is back up is all well and good... but what to check?  That there was recently a deposit for $100?  Not really reliable... Suggestion by a co-worker was to request a transaction ID from the WCF Service and pass this to the actual deposit call... though this seems to get complex fairly quickly.

Comment: you could request whatever you wanted... as long as your willing to build it... you could hash the data from the transaction itself and check against the hash client side as well.  Your right.  It does have the potential to get very complex, very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an EAI provider like BizTalk to orchestrate to the WCF services, and set up compensating operations for each of the operations that the services expose, so that a rollback can be performed in the event of failure.

Comment: I will look into that more... for now, it's a big learning curve, and a lot of software/hardware/setup... don't think I can do it in the short-term : (